# How to check the data rentention time for time travel for a specific database in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How do I check the time retention period for a specific database in snowflake? I know this is to do it for the account level, SHOW PARAMETERS like '%DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS%' in account;
but need it for a database

Answer (score 0):

One way can be `show databases` -

Use `SHOW DATABASES` and then `result_scan` to filter for specific database as needed.

(Output truncated - columnwise)

```
show DATABASES;
```

| name | retention_time |
| --- | --- |
| SNOWFLAKE | 1 |
| SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA | 1 |
| TEST_DB | 1 |

```
alter database test_db set DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS=2;
```

Check for specific database (after running, `show databases`) -

```
select "name","retention_time" from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "name" like '%TEST%';
```

| name | retention_time |
| --- | --- |
| TEST_DB | 2 |

Along with `show parameters` -

```
show parameters like '%retention%' in database TEST_DB;
```

| key | value | default | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS | 2 | 1 | DATABASE |